# Typescript ESLint error for prefer-rest-params

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm trying to integrate the Segment.io analytics snippet into a Typescript project.

Getting an ESLint error I can't work out. Here's the code:

```
analytics.factory = function (method: any) {
  return function () {
    const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
    args.unshift(method)
    analytics.push(args)
    return analytics
  }
}
```

And the error is:

```
error  Use the rest parameters instead of 'arguments'  prefer-rest-params
```

My Typescript is a bit rusty, I've tried the following to no avail:

- Array.prototype.slice.call(this, ...arguments)
- Array.prototype.slice.call(null, ...arguments)

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: [As the rule suggests](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-rest-params) use rest parameters, not the `arguments` keyword: `function (...args) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who lands here with a similar problem, here's the fix:

```
analytics.factory = function(method: any) {
  return function(...args: any[]) {
    args.unshift(method);
    analytics.push(args);
    return analytics;
  };
};
```

Comment: You don't *need* `const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(argz);` - it just converts `argz` to an array and `argz` is *already* an array. Remove that line and rename the definition to `function(...args: any[])`. Again, the rule clearly explains what is and isn't valid, so I don't know where you got this code from.

Comment: Updated as suggested